# How to restrict the user should give value for an text field depending upon dropdown response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i am having 2 fields.. one is drop down select box. second one is text box.. In dropdown there having 2 value numeric and alpha.. If user select alpha value from dropdown, then text box should accept only alpha value.. If user select numeric, then text box should accept only numeric value..

Here is my sample code..

```
<script>
    function isAlpha()
    {
        $("#Label").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which < 97 /* a */ || e.which > 122 /* z */) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }

    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    function NumAlpha()
    {
        var Alpha_Numeric = document.getElementById('Attribute').value;

        if (Alpha_Numeric == 1)
        {
            isAlpha();
        }
        else
        {
            isNumberKey(evt);

        }
    }

</script>

<select  name="Attribute[]" class="required" id="Attribute" >
    <option selected  value="">Field Attribute</option>
    <option value="1">Alpha</option>
    <option value="2">Numeric</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="Label[]" class="required" id="Label" onkeypress="return NumAlpha();"   onClick="field_length();" placeholder="Field Label" class="form-control">
```

In this code concept is working for alpha only.. But it is not working for numeric value.. Please share me some idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try It.

```js
function change(evt){
 var dd=document.getElementById("slt1").value;
 if (dd == "a"){
 return ValidateAlpha(evt);
 }else{
 return isNumberKey(evt);
 }
}
function isNumberKey(evt){  <!--Function to accept only numeric values-->
    //var e = evt || window.event;
 var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
        return true;
}     
function ValidateAlpha(evt)
{
 var keyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
 if ((keyCode < 65 || keyCode > 90) && (keyCode < 97 || keyCode > 123) && keyCode != 32)
  
 return false;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input id="txt1" type="text" onkeypress='return change(event);'></input>

<select onchange="document.getElementById('txt1').value=null;" id="slt1">
<option selected="selected" value="a">Alpha</option>
<option value="b">Numberic</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
$(document).on('change', '.dropdown', function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('.input').attr('required', false);
    $('#' + selected).attr('required', required);
})

<!-- HTML -->
<select name="" id="input" class="form-control" required="required">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="input" id="a" />
<input type="text" class="input" id="b" />
```

**Note: this is untested code**

Answer (score 0):

> You can try like as below code

**HTML Code**

```
<select onchange="selectAlNum(this)"  name="Attribute[]" class="required" id="Attribute" >
    <option selected  value="">Field Attribute</option>
    <option value="1">Alpha</option>
    <option value="2">Numeric</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="Label[]" class="required" id="Label" onkeydown="return NumAlpha(event)"  placeholder="Field Label" class="form-control">
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var AlNumValue = 0;

function selectAlNum(e){
    document.getElementById('Label').value = '';
    AlNumValue = e.value;
}

function NumAlpha(e){
    var value = e.which;
    if (AlNumValue==1) {
        /*Only Alpha are allowed*/
        if((value>=65 && value<=90)|| (value>=48&&value<=57)){
            return true;
        }
    }else if(AlNumValue==2){
        /*Only Numbers are allowed*/
        if((value>=96 && value<=105)|| (value>=48&&value<=57)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(value==8){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. Let me tell you how your code is woking from my side..After entering value.. if i try to delete.. it is not deleting the characters.. Also alpha options accepting numeric value as well @Sumon Sarker

Comment: I updated the answer. Added `if(value==8){
          return true;
        }` Now you can delete characters. @Nithya